# getting factory.php line 321 error during composer installation

Tags: json, installation, composer-php

```
In Factory.php line 321:

  "./composer.json" does not match the expected JSON schema:
   - name : Does not match the regex pattern ^[a-z0-9]([_.-]?[a-z0-9]+)*/[a-z0-9](([_.]|-{1,2})?[a-z0-9]+)*$
```

firstly try to do from c derive then again tried with E drive but still same error.

Comment: Please share more details, like the current state of your `composer.json` and your attempts to resolve the problem. What makes you think that changing the drive could help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a name like "**vendor/package_name**" =)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: For those answer is unclear in  the name key they value should be like "laravel/laravel" if you write this without the "/" you will get the error